# Importing data from firebase to bigquery

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to import data from firebase to big query upon `onWrite` event and getting same error each time function is triggered given below.

> PartialFailureError: A failure occurred during this request.
>       at /user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/bigquery/src/table.js:1086:13
>       at Object.handleResp (/user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/bigquery/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/src/util.js:134:3)
>       at /user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/bigquery/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/src/util.js:465:12
>       at Request.onResponse [as _callback] (/user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/bigquery/node_modules/retry-request/index.js:120:7)
>       at Request.self.callback (/user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/bigquery/node_modules/request/request.js:188:22)
>       at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
>       at Request.emit (events.js:191:7)
>       at Request. (/user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/bigquery/node_modules/request/request.js:1171:10)
>       at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
>       at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)

my function code is

```
exports.addtobigquery = functions.database.ref('/mn_users').onWrite(event => 
{
  const dataset = bigquery.dataset(functions.config().bigquery.datasetname);
  const table = dataset.table(functions.config().bigquery.tablename);

  return table.insert({
    id: event.data.key,
    name: event.data.val().name,
    email: event.data.val().email
  });

});
```

I want to figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: did you ever get it working?